# Django-Nginx, 502-BAd Gateway Error

Tags: django, nginx, django-haystack

I have implemented a Search page for my website on Django-Nginx platform. When I pass a long string as a GET parameter to search page, server return "502 Bad Gateway" error. The error logs shows "failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream". Please guide me to resolve this issue.

Comment: What's between django and nginx ? You should patse the logs of that.

Comment: How are you deploying it? What's the timeout value in the website's configuration file?

Comment: How long is the search taking?  If it is a lengthy operation it could be a timeout issue. What are you using between django and nginx-  fastcgi, gunicorn, uwsgi?